# Matrix of a relation on a set

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, relations

If I have a Matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ why is this both symmetric and anti-symmetric? If I had a Matrix $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ would this also be symmetric and anti-symmetric?

Comment: Define your terms, please, or at least give a reference. In particular, "anti-symmetric" isn't a term that is typically applied to matrices (so far as I know), so I wonder if "symmetric" may mean something different in this context, as well.

Comment: R is a symmetric relation, if and only if
 m_ij = 1 whenever m_ji = 1.
R is an antisymmetric relation, if and only if
 m_ij = 0  or m_ji = 0 when  i≠ j.

Comment: They are relation (incident) matrices, @Cameron, with $1$ representing a pair of elements are related by a given relation, and $0$ meaning they are not in the relation.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus: Recall: for antisymmetric, we want $A = -A^T$

Comment: I was just told that if there are all 1's down the diagonal, it is reflexive. If everything to the upper right of the diagonal matches everything to the bottom left of the diagonal, it's symmetric. If not, it's anti. But then I have an example of this 3x3 and it says it is both. This course has no books, only powerpoint. Sorry for the question but that is all the infomation I have.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus: For a symmetric matrix, we have $A = A^T$. Both your examples satisfy that (verify it). For antisymmetric, we want $A = -A^T$. The first satisfies that, the second does not. Here is a matrix that is antisymmetric $A = \{\{0, -1\},\{1,0\}\}$. Show $A = -A^T$. Clear?

Comment: $-0=0$${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first matrix represents the empty relation on a $3$-element set.  So both symmetry and anti-symmetry are satisfied vacuously.

Now $B$ represents the relation on a $3$-element set where any two elements are related.  Hence, it is symmetric, but not anti-symmetric (e.g $1 \sim 2$ and $2 \sim 1$, but $1 \ne 2$ )